# yii2 cant get view passed parameter in controller

Tags: yii2

can anyone please tell me why im getting this error ?
(the parameter is set i can get it value by echo)

```
Too few arguments to function app\controllers\admin\SiteDeveloperController::actionView(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

+info 
i passed user identity to view file by mycontroller indexaction so i can access the user id in view with $user->id ;

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $this->layout = "site-developer";

    if (Yii::$app->user->can('superuser')) {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
            return $this->render("index", [
                'user' => $user
            ]);
        } else {
            echo "you cant access this";
        }
    } else {

        throw new ForbiddenHttpException("you cant access this");
    }


}
```

no im trying to pass the current $user->id to mycontroller actionView  ... but it say (ArgumentCountError
0 passed and exactly 1 expected)

```
   public function actionView($id)
    {


        $mode = $this->findModel($id);


        print_r($mode);
//return $this->render("view");
    }
```

and this is the button that pass the id to controllers action

```
 <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><br>پروفایل',['view','id' => $user->id],['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'])?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after few hours + deep search i find out my controller name space is  yii**base**\Controller; it should be use yii**web**\Controller;
i hope it help some yii2 user for decrease thier debug time